# Why is "which" applicable here?

Tags: restrictive-clauses

The sentence is below (standalone sentence, no context)

> Bears often hide themselves in places ____ hunters can't find.

My teacher said the answer was "that/which". I feel totally OK with *that*, but am confused about why *which* is also applicable here.

IMHO, *which* leads a **non-restrictive clause** while *that* leads a **restrictive clause**. Since *hunters can't find* isn't an additional description of the noun *places*, *which* is not suitable here. And because it restricts *places* to *those that hunters can't find*, *that* should be OK here. Am I right?

Comment: The use of "that" vs. "which" is not as formal as you've probably been taught.  Please see the linked answer in StoneyB's comment for more information.

Comment: Stylistically, preference would be (1) nothing in the blank; (2) "that"; (3) "which". Grammatically all are acceptable; some statements of the case would reject (3) for exactly the reason you described, but -- for better or for worse -- it can often be seen and heard in the wild despite that "rule". I had one high-quality linguistics textbook whose author almost exclusively used "which" there. I found it frustrating, but enlightening.